# Regular expression to match all words in and including a given word

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression (using JavaScript) to match all 3-6 letter words that contain all or some subset of the letters in a given word. For example, if my word is "rescue", then I should match "use", "cure", "reuse", "secure", and so on. What I have right now is:

```
\b(?!\w*(\w)\w*\1)[rescue]{3,6}\b
```

...And this works, but for the repeat letters. It won't match words with 2 e's:

[image]

`r`, `e`, `s`, `c`, `u`, `e`, should match at most 1 `r`, `s`, `c`, and `u`, with at most  2 `e`'s.

Here I'm stuck. I'm not great at these things and it's a wonder I've come this far. This is not an operation I need to perform quickly or frequently, and the word list in only 20,000 words or so. I'm not concerned with the most efficient solution. I would love some help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you specify the programming language you are using ?

Comment: JavaScript. I've added language to question & tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the negative lookahead, as how it is currently written, this part `(?!\w*(\w)\w*\1)` asserts that what is to the right is not a word char `(\w)` that can occur again with `\w*\1`

Instead you could assert the length first, and then match one of the characters `r` `e` `s` `c` `u` `e`

```
\b(?!\w*([rescue])\1)(?=\w{3,6}\b)\w*[rescue]\w*\b
```

See a [regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/0O76AT/1).

If the word can only consist of the listed characters:

```
 \b(?!\w*([rescue])\1)[rescue]{3,6}\b
```

See another [regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/5KXLho/1).

Comment: Thank you for that explanation, that is helpful. The answer has the opposite problem as mine, though. It matches on any repetition. For example, it will match `eeeeee` ([shown here](https://regex101.com/r/Z39W7T/1).

Comment: @tarrball You can exclude only repeating characters like this https://regex101.com/r/CnenzV/1 `\b(?!([rescue])\1+\b)(?=\w{3,6}\b)\w*[rescue]\w*\b`

Comment: That's not quite it either, it's not taking into account the right number of letters https://regex101.com/r/fHDmHk/1

Comment: @tarrball Can you update the sheet with strings that should and should not match? There should be 3 - 6 characters right? Should the duplicates not exists after a certain amount?

Comment: @tarrball Should it be just at least 2 characters? https://regex101.com/r/8hUZaq/1

Comment: @tarrball I have updated the answer with 2 variations not matching 2 of the same characters right after each other for the given range.

Comment: @tarrball With those rules, the pattern will be a bit longer `^(?=\w{3,6}$)(?!(?:[^r\n]*r){2})(?!(?:[^s\n]*s){2})(?!(?:[^c\n]*c){2})(?!(?:[^u\n]*u){2})[rescu]*(?:e[rescu]*(?:e[rescu]*)?)?$` https://regex101.com/r/5RZUor/1

Comment: I think the second answer you gave in your answer is working... I might've just been seeing an issue with regex101

Comment: There's still some issues I've discovered in the pattern in your answer, but that longer one you put in your last comment seems right. It seems like this pattern would be a nightmare to generalize for any six letter word, so now I'm thinking I might need to look for non-regex solutions, or start reading [Mastering Regular Expressions](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/583628.Mastering_Regular_Expressions) :)